# Valid and Invalid HTML tags

Tags: html

So recently I found a question that was
Which of the following is a valid tag?

1. <213person>
2. <_person> (This is given as the right answer)
3. Both
4. None

(Note: this is the explanation that was given:- Valid HTML tags are surrounded by the angle brackets and the tag name can only either start from an alphabet or an underscore(_))

As far as my knowledge goes none of the reserved tags start with an underscore and according to what I've read about custom HTML tags it has to start with an alphabet(I tested it and it doesn't work with a custom tag starting with any character that's not an alphabet). So in my opinion and according to what I tested HTML tags can only start with alphabets or! (in case of !-- -- and !DOCTYPE HTML)

What I want to know is if the given explanation is correct or not and if it's correct then can someone provide some proper documentation and working examples for it?

Comment: Maybe this? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for providing this documentation. And can I infer that valid HTML tags can't start with either underscore or numeric characters?

Comment: Sorry, I'm by no means fluent in EBNF. But I think it's mandatory to start with a-z (so everything else, numbers, underscore... is not allowed). I'm also not 100% sure if it's Custom Elements what the trivia was referring too.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález well I'm also not quite sure what they were referring to but in any case it seems that the two given tags must be invalid by the standards. Thanks for the help mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Rob, the standard defines a valid tag name as string containing alphanumeric ASCII characters, being:

```
0-9|a-z|A-Z
```

However, browsers handle things differently.

There's a few main points that I've noticed which don't align with the [current standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name).

**Tag names must start with a letter**

If a tag name starts with any character outside `a-z|A-Z`, the start tag ends up being interpreted as text and the end tag gets converted into a comment.

**Special characters can be used**

The following HTML is valid in a lot of browsers and will create an element:

```html
<Z[\]^_`a></Z[\]^_`a>
```

This seems to be browsers only checking if the characters are ASCII. The only exception is the first character (as stated above).

Initially, I thought this was a simplified check, so instead of `[A-Z]|[a-z|` they checked `[A-z]`, but you can use *any* character outside this range.

This makes the following HTML also "valid" in the eyes of certain browsers:

```
<a!></a!>
<aʬ></aʬ>
<a͢͢͢></a͢͢͢>
<a͢͢͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ΘΘΘΘ></a͢͢͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ʬ͢ΘΘΘΘ>
<a￼></a￼>
```

*I tested the HTML elements in both Chrome and Firefox, I didn't test any other browsers. I also didn't test every ASCII character, just some very high and low in terms of their character code.*

Comment: So by the standard, answer #1 is correct. #2 is not correct in any case. #4 is correct by browser interpretation.

Comment: "Current standard" as stated by W3C [on this page](https://www.w3.org/html/)

Comment: Thanks for answering @Rylee and testing out several cases and comparing with the current standards.

Answer (score 1):

[From the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag):

> Start tags must have the following format:
>
> The first character of a start tag must be a U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN
> character (<). The next few characters of a start tag must be the
> element's tag name.

So what is allowed in the element's tag name? This is defined just above:

> Tags contain a tag name, giving the element's name. HTML elements all
> have names that only use ASCII alphanumerics. In the HTML syntax, tag
> names, even those for foreign elements, may be written with any mix of
> lower- and uppercase letters that, when converted to all-lowercase,
> matches the element's tag name; tag names are case-insensitive.

Comment: By this definition, though, HTML elements cannot contain dashes or underscores, as they are not "ASCII alphanumerics".

Comment: I agree with @HereticMonkey and you may read Rylee's answer for more details and test out some cases for yourself. Thank you for answering though.